# Webdav Nautilus 16.04 Configuration

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

The [instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/203432/how-to-access-ftp-and-webdav-sites-in-any-operating-systems-file-manager/) to setup a webdav folder indicate add the webdav URL in the  dialogue box:

[image]

http and https prefixes fail to 'light up' (enable) the connect button.

smb prefixes enable the connect button.

What needs to be done to enable the webdav connection?

Comment: There is no gvfs backend for "http". I suspect what you are looking for is "dav" or "davs". For example: `davs://mydomain.duckdns.org.....` OR `dav://mydomain.duckdns.org.....`

Comment: @Moribius1  If you would like credit, please publish your response as an "Answer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, thanks:

There is no gvfs backend for "http".

I suspect what you are looking for is "dav" or "davs". For example: `davs://mydomain.duckdns.org.....`

OR `dav://mydomain.duckdns.org.....`

Comment: `davs://` solved the problem